# Non-mandatory copy elision in catch clause

Tags: c++, optimization, c++17, try-catch

Reference: [Copy Elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

> Excerpts:
>
> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are permitted, but
> not required to omit the copy and move (since C++11) construction of
> class objects even if the copy/move (since C++11) constructor and the
> destructor have observable side-effects.
>
> In a catch clause, when the argument is of the same type (ignoring
> cv-qualification) as the exception object thrown, the copy of the
> exception object is omitted and the body of the catch clause accesses
> the exception object directly, as if caught by reference (there cannot
> be a move from the exception object because it is always an lvalue).

Given this premise, will the first catch clause also result in copy-elision? Or will only the second result in copy-elision?

```
uniquePtrObj makeObj(type args){

  uniquePtrObj = make_unique<obj>(args);//depending on memory required, this could
                                        //result in bad_alloc being thrown
 
 return uniquePtrObj;
}

int main (){

   try{
       
        uniquePtrObj = makeObj(type args);//allocates heap memory

    }catch(std::exception e){}//will this also result in copy-elision?
    }catch(std::bad_alloc e){}//or only this will result in copy-elision?

 return 0;
}
```

TIA

Comment: What is the question, can't get it.

Comment: Huh. Never heard the term "URVO" before, and now somebody edited cppreference to use it...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Unnamed Return Value Optimization (URVO) as reproduced from the above link

Comment: @AlanBirtles the question is embedded in the pseudo-code (I thought it would be evident) as comments against the catch clauses...

Comment: Not obvious at all, especially with the way you've formatted the code I can't even see the comments without scrolling. Ask your question in the text of the post, not in code comments

Comment: @AlanBirtles I just edited the question to point to the comments embedded in the pseudo-code outlining the questions...hope it is clearer now

Comment: It is confused question as "unnamed return value optimization" is not about throws and catches. It is about return values as name says.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I have reproduced the excerpt related to catch clause in my question...I don't get the confusion aspect of it?

Comment: @Vinod read your cite: "In the initialization of an object, when the source object is a nameless temporary and is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the target object. When the nameless temporary is the operand of a return statement, this variant of copy elision is known as URVO, "unnamed return value optimization." That is not about throws and catches but "operand of a return statement".

Comment: @ÖöTiib thanks I have modified my original question

Comment: I would argue (though not from a strictly "language-lawyer" perspective) that, as the `std::exception` object is polymorphic (has a virtual destructor), then it can be considered (in this context) as 'the same type' as `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: ... but shouldn't your catch clauses be the other way around? How would the second ever  be used, as `bad_alloc` will be a match for `std::exception`, I think. Yeah: MSVC warns: *warning C4286: 'std::bad_alloc': is caught by base class ('std::exception')*

Comment: @AdrianMole I had provided both the catch clauses to make my point...I would only be using one in my code....I wanted to get the opinion of this forum before deciding on which one to use...as part of my optimization

Comment: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Re-exception-ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the excerpt indicates, this form of copy elision can only occur when the object declared by the catch clause has the same type as the exception object, other than top-level cv-qualification. In the first catch clause, the type caught is a base class of the exception object's class, so copy elision cannot occur.

To see why copy elision isn't allowed in such cases, consider the general case of

```
try {
    throw Derived ();
} catch (Base b) {
    b.virtualFunction();
}
```

As written, this requires slicing to occur (whether the programmer intended it or not): the derived class's overrider of the virtual function can't be called, because the programmer requested the creation of an independent, complete `Base` object (not a reference to the `Base` part of a possibly derived object). If the compiler decided to elide the copy by making `b` into a reference, the behaviour would change because the overriding function in `Derived` would get called.